# Using VBA, I want to export a sheet as a CSV file but somehow add today's date. It'll be a daily export- hence the need for a date

Tags: vba

The code for exporting my specific sheet:

```
Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim Sales As Worksheet

Set Sales = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales") 
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                       
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:=" C:\Temp\MyCsv.Csv”, FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Since this process will be done daily, I want to somehow add on the today's date to sheet name. So, I can differentiate the files from each other (with respect to date)

I'm guessing I somehow need to incorporate this code really not sure though:

```
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
szToday = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sales" & szToday
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Do I need to add export in there? Or you just using that as a dummy file path. Let's say my file path is as follow: C:\Temp\. Does that mean to save the file name just as the date it'd be "C:\Temp\" & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY") & ".Csv"?

Comment: That was just an example - you can use whatever file name you like

Comment: You've not accepted any answers to your previous questions - you might want to revisit those and flag any useful responses using the "check".  This helps anyone coming along later to see there's a solution posted.  Also it's nice to recognize the effort of the people who took time to suggest things...

Comment: Oh very sorry. Quite new to this. Will make sure I do this! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no "sheet name" in a CSV file, so you only need to work with the filename:

```vb
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\" & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY") & ".csv", _
                 FileFormat:=xlCSV
```